# Sudoku puzzles - best way to learn it?

Tags: sudoku

What's the best way to learn Sudoku? Are there good websites with methods to do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is too broad and opinion-based for a reasonable answer within Puzzling Stack Exchange's format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grandmaster Puzzles](https://www.gmpuzzles.com) has a blog with [tips and tricks for solving puzzles](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/category/other-posts/askdoctorsudoku/). Most of the posts are about Sudoku. There are also a lot of [Sudokus you can practice on](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/category/sudoku/classic-sudoku/) and many of them have solution videos.

Answer (score -4):

Sudoku is a popular logic-based number placement puzzle that involves filling a $9 \times 9$ grid with digits so that each column, each row, and each of the nine $3 \times 3$ subgrids that compose the grid (also called "boxes", "blocks", or "regions") contain all of the digits from 1 to 9. If you're looking to learn how to solve Sudoku puzzles efficiently, here are some tips:

- **Understand the Rules**: Make sure you understand the basic rules of Sudoku: each row, column, and $3 \times 3$ subgrid must contain the numbers 1 through 9 without repetition.
- **Start with Easy Puzzles**: Begin with easy-level Sudoku puzzles. These typically have more filled-in numbers, making it easier to identify the next steps.
- **Scan Rows and Columns**: Look for rows and columns with the most filled-in numbers. These are usually the easiest to work with initially.
- **Identify Missing Numbers**: Identify missing numbers in rows, columns, and subgrids. This helps you narrow down the possible placements for a given number.
- **Use Pencil Marks**: Many people find it helpful to make small pencil marks in the corners of each cell, indicating possible candidate numbers. As you eliminate possibilities, erase or update these marks.
- **Check Subgrids**: Pay attention to the 3x3 subgrids. Once you identify a number in one of them, it can help eliminate possibilities in the corresponding rows and columns.
- **Apply Elimination**: Use the process of elimination. If a number can only go in one particular cell in a row, column, or subgrid, place it there.
- **Look for Pairs and Triples**: Search for pairs or triples of numbers in rows, columns, or subgrids. If you find a row with two empty cells and two possible numbers, those numbers can be placed in those cells.
- **Practice Regularly**: Sudoku is a skill that improves with practice. Regularly solving puzzles will help you develop techniques and strategies for tackling more challenging ones.
- **Gradually Increase Difficulty**: Once you feel comfortable with easy puzzles, gradually move on to medium, hard, and expert-level Sudoku puzzles. The more you practice, the more advanced solving techniques you'll become familiar with.

Remember, the key to becoming proficient at Sudoku is patience and practice. As you gain experience, you'll start to recognise patterns and develop your own strategies for solving puzzles.

Comment: Did you write this or was this AI generated? This comes up as 97% likely AI generated when checking online

Comment: I used GPT 3.5, but agreed with what it wrote. I know how to play sudoku, but I was looking to improve my technique.